# changing main image with a click not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to change my main image when I click on it , I did `console.log` and it is giving me this error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'src' of null` , I am doing something wrong with `this` attribute ? How can I click on my `img-container` to show up as a main image ? Thanks in advance !

my divs

```
<ul class="list-inline ">
<div class="main_image"><img src="some.jpg" ></div>

<li><div class="img-container"><img src="some.jpg" ></div></li>
<li><div class="img-container"><img src="some.jpg" ></div></li>
</ul>
```

jquery

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
$(".img-container img").click(function() {
    $(".main_image img").attr("src", $(this).attr("src"));
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Unable to reproduce http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/smwej5fw/

Comment: You code works. The problem may be somewhere else.

Comment: @Risbo, are you sure the DOM elements are not dynamically added after page loaded? In that case, your script runs but cannot find the relevant element thus raise that error

Comment: Are you sure your DOM elements are not appended by script?
Why don't you make the same in jsfiddle? Have you tested with other scripts if they work?

Comment: Thanks guys, I've had conflict with my other code. I've had too many div's around my images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the answer to your question as I can not reproduce the problem, but I will give you this alternate solution...

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$(".img-container img").click(function() {
    //$(".main_image img").attr("src", $(this).attr("src"));
    var img = $(this).clone();
    $(".main_image img").remove();
    $(".main_image").append(img);
});
});
```

Example here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e0xkavy8/)

Answer (score 0):

why are you using "this"?, you could just find the element with jquery

```
$(".main_image img").attr("src", $("#myElement").attr("src"));
```

Comment: He is using this because he wants to get the clicked element! The code he provided works fine!

Comment: that still doesn't answer the unreproducible problem.